# Library expects symbol in flat namespace although compiled with two-level namespace

Tags: python, c++, macos, linker, symbols

I load Python dynamically with `dlopen` and `RTLD_LOCAL` to avoid collisions with another library which by coincidence contains a few symbols with the same name. Executing my **MVCE** above on macOS with Xcode fails because it expects `_PyBuffer_Type` in the global namespace.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "...lib/python2.7/ctypes/__init__.py", line 10, in <module>
    from _ctypes import Union, Structure, Array
ImportError: dlopen(...lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/_ctypes.so, 2):
    Symbol not found: _PyBuffer_Type
  Referenced from: ...lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/_ctypes.so
  Expected in: flat namespace
 in ...lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/_ctypes.so
Program ended with exit code: 255
```

But why? Does `RTLD_LOCAL` overwrite the two-level namespace?

I used `otool -hV` to check that _ctypes.so was compiled with the Two-Level namespace option. From my understanding the symbol resolve needs the library name + the symbol name itself. Why does it expect `_PyBuffer_Type` in the flat namespace and/or why can't it find it? See `TWOLEVEL` by scrolling to the right

```
> otool -hV /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/_ctypes.so
Mach header
      magic cputype cpusubtype  caps    filetype ncmds sizeofcmds      flags
MH_MAGIC_64  X86_64        ALL  0x00      BUNDLE    14       1536   NOUNDEFS DYLDLINK TWOLEVEL
```

Any idea whats going on here?

### MVCE

Can be copied to a new Xcode project, simply compile and execute.

```
#include </System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/include/python2.7/Python.h>
#include <dlfcn.h>

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    auto* dl = dlopen("/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Python", RTLD_LOCAL | RTLD_NOW);
    if (dl == nullptr)
        return 0;

    // Load is just a macro to hide dlsym(..)
    #define Load(name)  ((decltype(::name)*)dlsym(dl, # name))

    Load(Py_SetPythonHome)("/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7");
    Load(Py_Initialize)();

    auto* readline = Load(PyImport_ImportModule)("ctypes");
    if (readline == nullptr)
    {
        Load(PyErr_Print)();
        dlclose(dl);
        return -1;
    }

    Py_DECREF(readline);
    Load(Py_Finalize)();
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This question and your related [RTLD_GLOBAL question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49394526/rtld-global-and-two-level-namespaces-on-macos/49480920#49480920) both concern the semantics of the dynamic loader resolving undefined symbols in the shared libraries that it loads. I was hoping to find an explicit documentation reference that would explain what you're seeing, but I've not been able to do it. Nonetheless, I can make an observation that may explain what's happening.

If we run with verbosity, we can see that the python library is attempting to load two shared libraries before it fails:

```
bash-3.2$ PYTHONVERBOSE=1 ./main 2>&1 | grep -i dlopen
dlopen(".../python2.7/lib-dynload/_locale.so", 2);
dlopen(".../python2.7/lib-dynload/_ctypes.so", 2);
```

Given that the first one succeeds, we know that generally the dynamic loader is resolving the undefined symbols against the namespace of the calling library. And in fact, as you note in the comments of your other question, this even works when there are two versions of the python library, i.e. the `dlopen()`s done by the python libraries resolve against their respective namespaces. So far, this sounds like exactly what you want. But, why is `_ctypes.so` failing to load?

We know that `_PyModule_GetDict` is the symbol that was causing `_locale.so` to fail to load in your other question; and that it obviously works here. We also know that the symbol `_PyBuffer_Type` is failing here. What's the difference between these two symbols? Looking them up in the python library:

```
bash-3.2$ nm libpython2.7.dylib | grep _PyModule_GetDict
00000000000502c0 T _PyModule_GetDict
bash-3.2$ nm libpython2.7.dylib | grep _PyBuffer_Type
0000000000154f90 D _PyBuffer_Type
```

`_PyModule_GetDict` is a `Text` (code) symbol, whereas `_PyBuffer_Type` is a `Data` symbol.

Therefore, based on this empirical data, I suspect the dynamic loader will resolve undefined symbols against `RTLD_LOCAL` code symbols of the calling library, but not `RTLD_LOCAL` data symbols. Perhaps somebody can point to an explicit reference.

Comment: Thanks for your great help!! I also think RTLD_LOCAL fails here bc the docs say `Symbols defined in this library are not made available to resolve references in subsequently loaded libraries` So `Py_Initialize` succeeds, but I saw that `_local.so` also fails, but it's also  not necessary to start Py. I think all in all, you are right with your other comment, that at least macOS does not support loading the same library more than once. (P.S. In case someone else reads this, on Win this works totally fine since c-modules have explicitly the pythonXX.dll as an internal dependency)

Comment: Again, thanks a lot for your contribution! I added a bounty to this question as well, which I can attach after 24h to your answer