# RTLD_GLOBAL and Two Level Namespaces on macOS

Tags: python, c++, python-3.x, macos, python-2.7

After reading the Apple documentation for [Executing Mach-O files](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/MachOTopics/1-Articles/executing_files.html) it says:

> The two-level namespace feature of OS X v10.1 and later adds the
>   module name as part of the symbol name of the symbols defined within
>   it. **This approach ensures a module’s symbol names don’t conflict with
>   the names used in other modules**.

So in my example I am loading *python2* and *python3* into the same process. Both Python libs are (by default) compiled with the two-level namespace option. Both libs are also loaded with the `RTLD_GLOBAL` flag via dlopen(..), so the symbols with the same name are supposed not to interfere with each other, since the two modules have different names (python27 and python36).

Example:

```
#include <{...}/include/python2.7/Python.h>

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    auto* py3 = dlopen(".../python36", RTLD_GLOBAL | RTLD_NOW);
    if (py3 == nullptr)
        return 0;

    auto* py2 = dlopen(".../python27", RTLD_GLOBAL | RTLD_NOW);
    if (py2 == nullptr)
        return 0;

    auto* init = ((decltype(Py_Initialize)*)dlsym(py2, "Py_Initialize"));
    if (init)
    {
        init();
    }

    return 0;
}
```

The problem is, after python2 imports `/path/to/python2/lib/lib-dynload/_locale.so`, the function `PyModule_GetDict` from python3 gets called. Why is that? How can that happen? Shouldn't the two-level namespace prevent that?

P.S. lib-dynload is a directory with additional C-modules for Python on macOS. I verified that the correct `_local.so` lib from the python2 environment gets loaded.

[image]

**Edit:**

After doing some experiments, I saw that the symbols of the first loaded python lib always get the higher precedence, not sure though if this is intended for first loaded libs or still 'undefined behaviour land'.

Calling Py_Initialize() of python27 - *Success:*

```
1. Loading python27 first
2. Loading python36 second
3. PYTHONHOME to python27
4. cal Py_Initialize() of python27
```

Calling Py_Initialize() of python27 - *Crash:*

```
1. Loading python36 first
2. Loading python27 second
3. PYTHONHOME to python27
4. cal Py_Initialize() of python27
```

I get the same results the other way around.

Calling Py_Initialize() of python36 - *Success:*

```
1. Loading python36 first
2. Loading python27 second
3. PYTHONHOME to python36
4. cal Py_Initialize() of python36
```

Calling Py_Initialize() of python36 - *Crash:*

```
1. Loading python27 first
2. Loading python36 second
3. PYTHONHOME to python36
4. cal Py_Initialize() of python36
```

Comment: What headers are you including and what's the command line that you're using for compilation?

Comment: Since I actually use absolute paths for the includes, dlopen and PYTHONHOME I can simply use `clang mvce.cpp -std=c++11 -o mvce` to reproduce it. I add an EDIT section to my post because there is an observation I made. Still can't wrap my head around it, why this happens despite the two-level namespace.

Comment: Have you tried RTLD_LOCAL? "Symbols exported from this image (dynamic library or bundle) are generally hidden and only availble to dlsym() when directly using the handle returned by this call to dlopen()."

Comment: Yes, `RTLD_LOCAL` was my idea before using `RTLD_GLOBAL` and it works for the startup routines. But since Python can load external C-modules, they fail to load because the symbols they need from the Python lib are hidden from them. I also opened a question for this, but I think `RTLD_GLOBAL` is the way to go. Still, In case you are interested to take a look, here is my other [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49393611/library-expects-symbol-in-flat-namespace-although-compiled-with-two-level-namesp)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The symbols within libpython (e.g. libpython2.7.dylib) are being resolved correctly. For example, under the above described scenario, I see `PyModule_GetDict()` get called 155 times before the incorrectly resolved call.

The problem is that python itself is compiling shared libraries, and it's using `dlopen()` to load them. You can see the `dlopen()` happening by setting the environment variable `PYTHONVERBOSE` when running:

```
$ PYTHONVERBOSE=1 ./main 2>&1 | grep dlopen
```

which produces:

```
dlopen(".../lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/_locale.so", 2);
```

The `2` argument corresponds to `RTL_NOW`, but that doesn't matter too much. The issue is that this separate library isn't able to indicate that it's symbols should be resolved against the libpython2.7.dylib library. Yet, it does have several python symbols; in particular, this one that ends up causing the problem:

```
$ nm prefix/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/_locale.so | grep GetDict
         U _PyModule_GetDict
```

So, when python `dlopen()`s the library, all it can do is resolve the symbol without the qualification. Apparently, the semantic of the `dl` functionality is to resolve such symbols based on the order the libraries are loaded, as you noted.

So, things work fine until we load `_locale.so`, as you can see from the following backtrace:

```
* thread #1, queue = 'com.apple.main-thread', stop reason = EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x50)
  * frame #0: 0x00000001003f3fc1 libpython3.6m.dylib`PyErr_FormatV [inlined] PyErr_Restore at errors.c:42 [opt]
    frame #1: 0x00000001003f3fb7 libpython3.6m.dylib`PyErr_FormatV [inlined] PyErr_Clear at errors.c:355 [opt]
    frame #2: 0x00000001003f3fb7 libpython3.6m.dylib`PyErr_FormatV(exception=0x00000001004cba18, format="%s:%d: bad argument to internal function", vargs=0x00007fff5fbfdcb0) at errors.c:841 [opt]
    frame #3: 0x00000001003f2c39 libpython3.6m.dylib`PyErr_Format(exception=<unavailable>, format=<unavailable>) at errors.c:860 [opt]
    frame #4: 0x0000000100358220 libpython3.6m.dylib`PyModule_GetDict(m=0x0000000101a5a868) at moduleobject.c:450 [opt]
    frame #5: 0x00000001000f491c _locale.so`init_locale at _localemodule.c:703 [opt]
    frame #6: 0x00000001018d1176 libpython2.7.dylib`_PyImport_LoadDynamicModule(name="_locale", pathname=".../lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/_locale.so", fp=<unavailable>) at importdl.c:53 [opt]
```

Also worth noting, `_locale.so` is just the first library to fail. If you got past it somehow, there are quite a few other libraries that potentially will have similar problems in `.../lib/python2.7/lib-dynload`.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your detailed answer ! I wasn't sure if the symbols of the first loaded libs really get the "precedence" or if this just works by coincidence and is still undefined behaviour land.

Comment: For me one of the key sentences in your answer is this one: `isn't able to indicate that it's symbols should be resolved against the libpython2.7.dylib library`. And that's why I am wondering, why is that? Executing `otool -hV` on all involved python libs (and c-module libs) shows me that they are all compiled with a `TWOLEVEL` flag. Do I maybe misunderstand it's purpose?

Comment: Regarding the ordering, I did find this relevant quote about global-scope searching from [Using Symbols](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/DynamicLibraries/100-Articles/DynamicLibraryUsageGuidelines.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001928-SW9): "The dynamic loader searches the dependent libraries (loaded at launch time) and the dynamically loaded libraries (loaded at runtime with RTLD_GLOBAL ) for the first match of the symbol name given to dlsym."

Comment: For example, _locale.so is compiled with TWOLEVEL. So, all of it's defined symbols will be qualified with the _locale.so library name. The problem you've described is related to how its undefined symbols are resolved. IMO, the TWOLEVEL approach is primarily intended to allow multiple libraries that happen to define the same symbols to peacefully coexist; which it does well. I think it's safe to say it's not really intended to allow `dlopen()`ed libraries to select between multiply-loaded versions of the same functionality.

Comment: Probably not a reasonable option for most situations, but if you could compile your own python, relink the libraries under `lib-dynload`, and explicitly link them against the  correct version of the python library, they would load correctly.

Comment: Some related discussion in: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49393611/library-expects-symbol-in-flat-namespace-although-compiled-with-two-level-namesp/